# Angular2 - Parameter $event implicitly has 'any' type

Tags: angular, events, angular2-forms

My main concern is that `$event` shows error in this line:

```
starClick($event) {
```

> Parameter $event implicitly has 'any' type

I also wonder - according to Angular2 docs, what `$event` does is captures the event object, so let me ask stupid question - why we don't call it `$object`? Because it made me confuse quite a bit until I finally realised whats happening here..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'stars',
  template: `
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" (click)= "starClick($event)"></span>
  `
})

export class StarsComponent {
  starClick($event) {
    if($event.target.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty") {
      $event.target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star";
    }
    else{
      $event.target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: '$event' in your case has MouseEvent type, you can add this in your method to avoid a warning.

Comment: `$event` is passed from EventEmitter. It would be `$object` if it were ObjectEmitter - but it's not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the below flag in tsconfig.json

> "noImplicitAny": true

You have 2 ways to fix this.

```
1. "noImplicitAny": false //Make this false

2. Mention the event type in component code, for eg.
```

For (click)="onClick($event)" should be captured in your component as

**onClick(event: KeyboardEvent)**

and

(mouseover)='onMouseOver($event)' should be captured as

**onMouseOver(event: MouseEvent)**

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav, this is very useful for me.

Answer (score 10):

I think that this is a warning and not an error, that you probably see in your code editor. You can avoid this simply by putting **any** as type of your parameter like:

```
starClick($event:any) { ...
```

**$event** is a convention of Angular and you should only use it in the HTML like:

```
<input type="text" (yourCustomEvent)="onYourCustomEventHandle($event)">
```

And you can name it as you wish in the typescript code like this:

```
onYourCustomEventHandle(apples){ ... }

onYourCustomEventHandle(oranges){ ... }
```

just name it as it makes more sense to you.
When using custom events you use **$event** to pass data to your handler.

When using it with the regular events like:

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)" (mouseover)='onMouseOver($event)'>
```

you simply get the event object as parameter in your code, but again you can name it as you wish in the code:

```
onClick(myClickEvent){ ... }
onClick(e){ ... }
onMouseOver(event){ ... }
onMouseOver(johnny){ ... }
```

**But don't forget to name it always $event inside the HTML**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solve it changing this code: `starClick($event: any)`. This is how it looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'stars',
  template: `
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" (click)= "starClick($event)"></span>
  `
})

export class StarsComponent {
  starClick($event: any) {
    if($event.target.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty") {
      $event.target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star";
    }
    else{
      $event.target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty";
    }
  }
}
```